# JavaScript Event Handler and CallBack Functions with Arguments Confusion

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-callback

Why does callback function passed in the form anonymous function for event handler ensure that callback function will execute after the callee function has executed?

So my question is:

Case 1:

`$.get( "myhtmlpage.html", myCallBack( param1, param2 ) ); //this wont work`

Case 2:

```
 $.get( "myhtmlpage.html", function() { // will execute $.get and then myCallBack

            myCallBack( param1, param2 );

             });
```

Why is it the case?

Answer (score 1):

At its core, JavaScript is a *single threaded* language with every action triggered by an *event*.

The browser waits around in an "event loop" for events to happen (e.g. user input device events, timer events, AJAX events, etc) and for each event it will call any registered *event handlers* (i.e. callbacks) that have been registered on that event.

Once the event handler has finished its work, return passes back to the "event loop".

So, when you call `$.get()` the jQuery library internally creates an `XMLHttpRequest` object and registers the supplied callback function as the event handler.

That function is not called immediately.  Any other code following the `$.get()` is run, and then control goes back to the event loop again.

*Eventually*, the `XMLHttpObject` will create an `onreadystatechange` event and add it to the queue of events waiting to be processed.

The event loop will see that event, find the registered callback, and invoke it.

Simples :)

Answer (score 0):

```
myCallBack( param1, param2 )
```

This is a function call, not a function statement, while you need a function as a parameter for $.get()'s second parameter.

You can also

```
$.get( "myhtmlpage.html", myCallBack);
```